# getting the address value without word alignment?

Tags: c#

I have this question:

suppose that the size of "char" is one byte and the size of "int" and "float" is 4 bytes.

```
struct Employee
{
int age;
char sex;
char name[25];
    float info[3][10];
};
Employee x;
```

what is the address of "x.info[2][5]" without word alignment, supposing that the adress of "x" is 1000 ?

note: this is not a homework but i had an exam and i answered this wronge.
I really wold like to know the right answer.

thanx

Comment: This is very low-level, and likely to be language-specific... is this C?

Comment: You don't tell us what x is - structure? union?  Can't answer without that information.

Comment: the language is not important its to know how to get the addresses values considering the word alignment

Comment: The `[homework]` tag isn't *literal* homework.  It can also be exams, midterms, extra credit...

Comment: X is struct sorry I missed that

Comment: @Kristian, the language is *fundamentally* important to answer this question.  Only the language specification could tell you whether that array is row- or column-major for example.

Comment: @Kristian -what's the definition of the structure - that matters too.

Comment: again sorry its C# and x is struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about other languages, but in C and C++ this is how a 2-D array will be stored in the memory:

Your `float info[3][10]` has 3*10 = 30 `float`s in the memory.

If the first memory location of your 2-D array is 1000 i.e `&info[0][0]` then your `&info[2][5]` will be 1000 + sizeof(float) * (2*10 + 5) = 1100 i.e first_memory_location + sizeof(data_type) * (row_no * total_no_columns + column_no).

Have a look at this [link](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html) to understand the concept better

EDIT: The same calculation holds good for 2-D arrays inside a struct.

In your case, there is an int, a char and a char array of size 25. So your `&info[0][0]` = 1029

First_memory_location + sizeof(float) * ( row_no * total_no_columns + column_no)

1029 + 4 *(2*10 + 5) = 1129

Comment: How is it 2129? Assuming that the address starts from 1000, your struct size itself is int(4 bytes) + char(1 byte) + char[25](25 bytes)  and float [3][10](4*3*10) = 150 bytes. 1000 + 150 ... your memory address should not go beyond 1149

Comment: @ srikfreak
I just called my instructor he said its right that the answer is 1100 but he said I should sum to that the (age and sex and name) (4+1+25) and as we are starting from 1000 (the 1000 is counted ) so it 1130 - (the 1000 address with is (1)) the final answer is 1129

Answer (score 0):

[I will suppose that X in your question is noise from an alien spacecraft]

Address &info[2][5] is then info[2]+5 = (char*)info+ sizeof(float)*2*10+5*sizeof(float) == (char*) info + 100

sizeof(float)==4

Comment: I got totaly lost with your answer !!

Comment: Lost where? the result is 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you need to add the memory space of all variables together in order, not just the address space of x.

So if the address of x is 1000, the address you want would be at

```
1000
+sizeof(int)         // age
+sizeof(char)        // sex
+(sizeof(char)*25)   // name
+(sizeof(float)*2*10) + sizeof(float)*5   // info[2][5]
```

Assuming usual sizes, that would be 1000 + 8 + 1 + 25 + 120 = 1154

Comment: wronge answer
what  srikfreak did was right but read the comments the final value is 1129